# Charging a 12vdc lead-acid battery bank with two different power sources (solar & wind)

Tags: battery-charging, solar-charge-controller, windturbine

Looking to upgrade an existing solar system with two (2) 285W panels going through a 40A MPPT solar charger. The solar charger is charging 4 6v lead-acid deep cycle batteries.

((Cell 1 + Cell 2) || (Cell 3 + Cell 4)) = ((6vdc+6vdc) || (6vdc+6vdc)) = (12vdc || 12vdc).

Over the past couple years, we have come to notice that we are draining the battery bank below nominal voltage on days that are preceded by two consecutive cloudy/rainy days. This leads to us having to cut our use of the 12vdc battery system.

I've come up with a couple different options.

First, the obvious, add a couple more 6v cells to get (12vdc || 12vdc || 12vdc) coupled with an additional 285W panel. The controller can easily handle the extra panel, but the new batteries will dupe down to the same age as the old batteries.

Second, we have quite a bit of constant wind. We are setup on a point on a lake. I've looked at some solar + wind hybrid controllers but have not found anything that really gets me excited. Those Chinese controllers just look sketchy af, I get the feeling I could design something more robust.

What I was thinking about doing is potentially getting a separate wind system with its own charger that outputs something around 12vdc. To bridge the gap with the old system, I would add a 12vdc to 12vdc charger towards the battery bank that has a dual 12vdc input. Meaning, I could simply plug the output of the solar MPPT charger in input 1, and the wind controller into input 2. This would lead to a controlled charging of the batteries with two separete sources. This would also allow me to have a robust wind controller with proper protection of the turbine.

Curious to know what other experts might think about going either of these two routes and the feasibility of said routes.

Is my proposed 12vdc to 12vdc system feasible?

Comment: Nothing wrong with a mix of solar and wind.

Comment: A mix of powersources is always a good idea... But this is a question and answer forum, so what is your question?

Comment: Similar (but not duplicate) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/590983/how-to-integrate-a-wind-turbine-with-an-already-installed-off-grid-solar-system#comment1549213_590983